# Manually Register AppInstaller for Current Package

Tags: c#, uwp

Here's the issue I'm trying to resolve:
If a user installs the UWP directly from the .appxbundle instead of using the .appinstaller file the program will not check in for updates.

Is there a way in code via the Windows.Management.Deployment framework to register an appinstaller Uri for the current package?

I've tried AddPackageByAppInstallerFileAsync, but unfortunately since the package is already registered on the computer it won't install on top of itself.

Comment: I'm confused about "If a user installs the UWP directly from the .appxbundle, the program will not check in for updates." When I install the package for the second time, the button will display "Update" in the dialog. What does "the program will not check in for updates" mean? Could you please show more details about it?

Comment: Thanks for following up. Maybe it will be better to explain my goal.

I would like the options to deploy the msixbundle or appxbundle for an application with Intune/Microsoft Line of Business. My issue is that Intune/Store isn't reliable enough for our needs to for pushing out new updates. 
I would like to use AppInstaller to utilize the background updates and user initiated update dialogs but unfortunately installing from the msixbundle/appxbundle will not associate the AppInstaller Uri. So I'm trying to find a way in app code to set the AppInstaller URI on launch if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, for your requirement, it is not feasible to achieve it.